# How to get token to edit a page using Wikipedia API

Tags: api, token, wikipedia

I want to create a system that can perform edit function in Wikipedia articles using its MediaWiki API.

I went through search in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit and https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-phpwikipedia/index.html links to start with but no good.

Basically, I am stuck where it is mentioned we need edit tokens to edit a page. However, I couldn't not get it.

If you guys can show me short code snippets to do this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how to get the token, the best approach is to use an api client framework, that way you neither don't have to reinvent the wheel, spend time upgrading it whenever API changes, and provably keep the app safer. In https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code you can check already developed api clients, now depends on what language / depth of the API client you'll need.